# How to test if you have -0.0 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm translating ssd_drive sizes with letters to terabytes to make it easier to read. I've found a case were there's a reported -13G (weird in and of itself). This causes my human2terabytes function to return -0.0. I'm going to modify the code to not not return -0.0 but I'm wondering how i'd have to deal with this return if I didn't control the code producing the result.

```
diskpool["ssd_free"] = common.human2terabytes("-13G")
diskpool["ssd_free"])
print(diskpool["ssd_free"]) # prints -0.0
print(diskpool["ssd_free"] == -0.0) # False
print(diskpool["ssd_free"] == 0) # False
print(diskpool["ssd_free"] == 0.0) # False
```

I'm not sure how to write a condition that tells you if you have -0.0

```
def human2terabytes(human_readable_string, precision=1):
    """
    >>> human2bytes('1M')
    1048576
    >>> human2bytes('1G')
    1073741824
    found at:
    https://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/source/browse/trunk/test/bench.py?spec=svn984&r=984#137

    Raises:
        Value Error: If human_readable_string is not a numeric value with 
            a single letter then this code will raise a value error.
    """
    bytes_in_terabyte = 1099511627776.0
    precision_string = "{0:." + str(precision) + "f}"

    if human_readable_string == "0":
        return precision_string.format(0)

    symbols = ("B", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z", "Y")
    letter = human_readable_string[-1:].strip().upper()
    num = human_readable_string[:-1]
    assert letter in symbols
    num = float(num)
    prefix = {symbols[0]: 1}
    for index, symbol in enumerate(symbols[1:]):
        prefix[symbol] = 1 << (index + 1) * 10
    num_bytes = int(num * prefix[letter])
    str_num_bytes = float(num_bytes / bytes_in_terabyte)
    return precision_string.format(str_num_bytes)
```

I want to just return  0 if I get a -0.0. But I'm not sure how to test

Comment: `if not result: return 0`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the problem is that the value isn't really `-0.0`, it's somewhere between 0.0 and -0.05 which gets rounded to -0.0 when converted to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the result of `precision_string.format(...)`, so it's a string and you need to compare it with a string:

```
print(diskpool["ssd_free"] == "-0.0")
```

That should say `True`. (Please check.)

Though to prevent/check it inside `human2terabytes`, you could also check `num_bytes`. Checking the original integer might be preferable over the string or the float, though it depends on the result you want.

Comment: In this case `num_bytes` will be -13958643712, it's only after division and rounding that it looks close to zero.

Comment: You are correct. I'm assuming this means `.format` uses ones compliment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `abs` and `copysign` to check the sign and value independently.

```
from math import copysign

value = float("-0.0")
epsilon = 10**-10
sign = copysign(1, value)
if abs(value) < epsilon and sign == -1:
    ...
```

EDIT:
I didn't notice `human2terabytes` returned a string, Stefan's answer is more suitable. I'll leave this here anyways.